# Visual Studio 2015 fails to evaluate variables when two versions of assembly are loaded

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

My .NET application can load multiple versions of the same assembly into memory. Assemblies are not signed but every time new copy of assembly is complied and loaded it automatically gets a new assembly version (in minor part). I do not have any issues with types since instantiation ob objects is under by control, so I know from which assembly the object is created.

This was working ever since VS 2003, but with the latest VS 2015 the debugging of this scenario is broken. All works fine while only single version of assembly is loaded into memory but whenever second version is being loaded all Locals/Watch windows become empty. And trying to evaluate any expression in QuickWatch gives a compiler exception *"error CS1704: An assembly with the same simple name 'MyAssembly' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (e.g. 'MyAssembly.dll') or sign them to enable side-by-side."*

Here are screenshots of the same application with attached debuggers from VS2013 and VS2015 (when two assemblies are loaded):

**VS2013 Debugger:**
[image: VS2013 Debugger]

**VS2015 Debugger:**
[image: VS2015 Debugger]

And the selected parts from loaded assemblies list:
[image: Two different versions of an assembly]

So this makes debugging with VS 2015 almost impossible.

Since originally this is a compliler error (which to my belief is used under the cover of VS 2015 debugger) internet search is not very useful. Here is the only link related to Debugger problem that I was able to find:
[Visual Studio Debugger Failing to inspect variables](https://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/visual-studio-2015-debugger-failing-to-inspect-variables/). The difference to my case is that there having two assemblies in memory was a mistake while in my case this is an intent.

So now I am thinking on my options.

- Of course, ideally I would like to have some patch to VS 2015 that will fix the issue. But being realistic I am not sure this will happen.
- Signing assemblies (as compiler suggests) is not an option since assemblies are generated on clients' machines and it is not possible to provide them with a key for signing.
- I could try to play with AppDomains to see if debugger could handle the case when assemblies are loaded to different domains. But even if it could, this would be quite a huge (and unplanned) change to my appliction.

So may be anyone could suggest some more ideas? Thnaks.

Comment: I realize you found a workaround already, but I don't understand why signing the assemblies is not an option here. You shouldn't have to provide them with a key (even though you easily could create one just for this purpose and let them use it), as your clients could create their own and use it to sign their own assemblies themselves. If this is more of a requirement than you are willing to enforce on your clients, you could even potentially sign the assembly yourself before loading it. The Strong Name Tool (sn.exe) can be used to sign an assembly after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this problem. There is an option in Visual Studio "Debug - Options - General - Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluator", enabling it restores previous debugger behaviour.

[image]

This option is described in [VS 2015 Known Issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025133) for different debugger issue but also works for described case.

I also filed a bug to Microsoft. I do not believe they will do anything about it, but here is the [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1983888/debugger-in-vs-2015-fails-to-evaluate-variables-when-two-versions-of-assembly-are-loaded-into-memory) just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an option in your situation, you could try to rename the class or namespace before loading the assembly.

There are libraries that can modify assembly files: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20565/Assembly-Manipulation-and-C-VB-NET-Code-Injection

This of course assumes that you are loading the assembly and types at runtime.

Comment: Lukas, thanks. The option you are suggesting is very reasonable but does not seem to be acceptable for me. I have some limited control over build process of client assemblies but I do not really want to interfere. Since client assemblies contain user code I believe users will not be happy that I perform some post-build hacking to their assemblies. So I prefer either to have a patch to VS or to do something with the code of my application that will allow debugger to work properly.